# how to load a .dat file during program start with < operator C#

Tags: c#, file, load

i have a *.dat file and i should load it when i start the program in the command line. e.g.
**programm.exe < data.dat**

the dat file contains just a 2D structure made of some signs.
e.g.

```
################
................
################
................
################
................
```

i want to load it and show it in WinForms.

If anyone has a hint where the "<" is specified. I just got the hint that i can be done without filehandling

Comment: Read from stdin.

Comment: Stdin means reading from System.Console.In and in your case use the ReadLine(Async) or ReadToEnd(Async) methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if command line always is **programm.exe < data.dat** then you can use:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = System.Console.In.ReadToEnd();
}
```

if the input is missing, this will wait for user input. you can use **async** preventing to block program execution when input is missing or is loading.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "";
    Task.Run(async () => { input = await System.Console.In.ReadToEndAsync(); });
}
```